# Progress towards badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

Via the review tab, it is possible to see your progress towards obtaining certain badges.

> For any badge which requires multiple instances of an activity (i.e. 80 edits, earned 200 reputation on 50 occasions, etc.) is it possible to see your progress? If not, why not?

I know that badges shouldn't be one's goal necessarily, but they seem to do their job in encouraging activity. Maybe being aware of how close or far you are from another badge would be more enticing.

Comment: Enticing progress toward certain badges is more likely to do harm than good. E.g., I can imagine users inserting minor edits in old posts to get the S&W badge. (One could search for "Holder" and [replace it with Hölder](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1374/must-we-raise-the-dead-for-umlauts-sake/), etc). I think it's better to *not* have progress bars for edit-based badges at least.

Comment: See also [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/) at meta.SO.

Comment: And also: [How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137959)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) to check on that. It used to have once-in-a-few-weeks-updates, but now it updates about once a week, so it's a rather reliable method.

You could also use the StackApps from [this guy](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/) to generate information.

Answer (score 5):

To see how many times you have reached 200 reputation (for the [Epic badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/42/epic)), look at [your reputation calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation); near the bottom, it says "earned at least 200 reputation on xx days".

To see how many edits you have (for the [Strunk & White badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white) or the [Copy Editor badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor)), go to the [Suggested Edits review page](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) and hover over the progress bar (as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120462/174208)). The progress on the Strunk & White or Copy Editor badges shows the number of edits counted.