# View sign-in history

Tags: support, user-interface, user-accounts, profile-page, user-profile

A few days ago I recall finding a visual calendar of my sign-in history on Math Stack Exchange. It looked like an ordinary monthly calendar, where the days were white if I hadn't signed in, and green if I had. (I found it when I wondering how close I've been in the past to getting the "fanatic" badge.)

However, I can no longer find this page/pop-up.

I thought it might have been a feature of Stack Exchange as a whole, but I was unable to find an answer on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: This seems to be answered here: [Statistics of visits on M.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24876). See also meta,SE: [Implementation date for the consecutive days calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68956) and [How can I see which days I visited site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128605). The [tag-info for the calendar tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/calendar/info) is also a reasonable place to find more information.

Comment: A brief answer is that you should go to [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) and click on the number of consecutive days. (Remember that you'll find this in the profile tab, not in the activity tab.)

Comment: Thank you! I clearly didn't search hard enough for preexisting answers.

Comment: Since you explicitly mentioned that this was interesting for you in part in connection with a badge, I'll add also link to this question: [Progress towards badges](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6955). And since that answer was posted, also the new feature called [badge tracking](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/badge-tracking/info) was introduced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A brief answer is that you should go to [your profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) and click on the number of consecutive days. (Remember that you'll find this in the profile tab, not in the activity tab.)

You can find more details here:

- [Statistics of visits on M.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24876)
- [Implementation date for the consecutive days calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68956)
- [How can I see which days I visited site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128605)
- The [tag-info for the calendar tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/calendar/info) is also a reasonable place to find more information.

(Originally I considered that this question could be closed as a duplicate of the first one in this list. But maybe they are slightly different after all - the other one asks also whether it is possible to see this information for other users, not just your own visits. That's why I decided to convert my comments to an answer.)

Answer (score 4):

When you click your own profile, the default tab is the activity tab. You should go to the "Profile" tab, where you can see the "visited $x$ days, $y$ consecutive" text. Click this text to show the calendar.

[image]

Comment: Wow, $x = y$. I wonder who else on math.SE has this level of attendance.

Comment: @achillehui  I think on math.SE this is unmatched. [There are two on SO with x=y and 3k+ days though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-3000-days-3000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile)

Comment: @quid: Give it a year... ;p

Comment: Sure. Those two just had a head-start. I believe to recall there is somebody on tex.se too with a comparable record. But I cannot locate the meta.se post where it came up. something about a display bug maybe.

Comment: Well, I'm sure there are others like me who check the website every day, and have been doing that for a long enough period. It's not hard, just requires basic dedication... :)